# Within leaflet, does fitBounds have a callback?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I have two types of searches for putting markers on a map. One search fires based on a search query from an input form and the other fires on the `moveend` event (i.e. "redo search on map movement"). The resultant data is not the same; the former uses a radius and the latter limits to within the bounds).

The issue is that with the query based search, I would like to fit the map to the markers returned. So, I use `fitBounds()` for this which delegates internally and animates a pan to the best bounds around the markers.

At the end of the animation it fires a `moveend` event firing off my other type of search and resetting my results, which is the behavior I do not want.

In order to work around the problem, I can use `setTimeout` and a known duration for the panning options on `fitBounds()`. With this, I can turn my event listener on `moveend` off, then `fitBounds` which takes .25 seconds, then `setTimeout` for .25 seconds (in practice, a little longer) with a callback to add the `moveend` listener back.

This works but it would be more practical if fitBounds or panning had an event or callback itself. Can you think of a better solution?

Comment: Can you put the affected code?

Comment: Also confused as to your setup. Posting the relevant code would go a long way here. Perhaps the `once` listener can be of use to you?

Answer (score 1):

You can use moveend + zoomend events to catch end of map fitting.
Because at least one of them called in the end of `fitBounds` execution

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to detect the "dragging" event on the map, I think it would be better to use `dragend` instead of `moveend`.

Comment: Just put the first sentence as a comment.  It shouldn't be part of the answer.

Comment: Using `dragend` instead of `moveend` is a fantastic idea and more or less works. The issue is we want to redo search when the zoom changes as well. `zoomend` is still fired by `fitBounds` whereas `dragend` is not.